# How to set timer to close one function then open another?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just want to set a timer of 20 seconds in a function then jump to another:

Function 1:

```
example_gif = gif_pygame.load("giphy (1).gif")
def animatedgif():
    while True:
        example_gif.render(screen, (200 - example_gif.get_width() * 0.5, 150 - example_gif.get_height() * 0.5))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit();
                sys.exit()
        crt_shader()
```

Function 2:

```
def first_question():

    while True:

        #screen.fill((255,255,255))
        render_text("Teste Teste",text_font,(255,255,255),0,0)   
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
        crt_shader()
```

I already tried threads ou multiprocess but i'm a quite beginner and the dont really understand how the explanations works.

The `pygame.time.wait` or `time.wait` won't working to. I'm looking to open a function after all, not waiting like a loading screen or something like the duplicates.

Comment: Yes, it works, but not for me. Read it again. The user wants to know other forms to do something that he already acchiev with this codes that i mention. Clearly the answears refers to other questions that nothing has to do with my question.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Exit a function on a timer" is, in general, _not a good design_ and you shouldn't be doing it in the first place. Look into state machines or event loops -- the way you're writing your program now it can't do more than one thing at a time, not even trivial things like responding to menu clicks. Once you follow good design practices this isn't a problem that you have.

Comment: That said, you _can_ make your timeout show up as a pygame event, and `return` when you see that particular event. See the [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module, **as the duplicates already tell you to do**; it shouldn't be a big leap to see `return` as a thing you can do when `event.get()` returns you a timer event scheduled with `pygame.time.set_timer()`.

Comment: (there are additional, worse ways to make a function exit on a timer, like sending a signal that throws an exception to the thread running a function, but they're Bad Ideas for a reason).

Comment: Tnx for helping me. I'm trying to user pygame.time.set_timer() but i'm confused about the USEREVENT, acctualy my screen just freezes and do nothing more.